# Error when indexing through an array with a loop

Tags: javascript

I'm making a simple quiz app and when get past the first question, which isn't part of the loop, it triggers the loop to start, whereby when you answer a question it indexes through the questions and gets you the next one, and does so with the answers. For my question array it won't index the second question for some reason, but this isn't a problem on my answers array.

I've already tried adding an empty string in between the two values and it had no effect, still came back "undefined". I also tried sticking an empty string in the start and it has no effect. Yet somehow I need to stick empty strings in between my sets of answers in the answers array.
Here is all the code you should need to answer my question, need anymore info just ask!

```
var readyButton = document.getElementById("readyButton"); // since people asked for full code
var question = document.getElementById("question");
var answerOne = document.getElementById("answer1");
var answerTwo = document.getElementById("answer2");
var answerThree = document.getElementById("answer3");
var answerFour = document.getElementById("answer4");
var answerOneData = document.getElementById("answer1data");
var answerTwoData = document.getElementById("answer2data");
var answerThreeData = document.getElementById("answer3data");
var answerFourData = document.getElementById("answer4data");
var answerOneDataT = document.getElementById("answer1dataT");
var answerTwoDataT = document.getElementById("answer2dataT");
var answerThreeDataT = document.getElementById("answer3dataT");
var answerFourDataT = document.getElementById("answer4dataT");
var nextAnswers = ["", "24", "25.5", "15", "32","", "a statement", "a question", "a sentence", "a metaphor"];
var nextQuestions = ["Find x in the equation: 2x+12=63", "This is an example of...",];
let possibilities = {
    'clicked1': 0,
    'clicked2': 0,
    'clicked3': 0,
    'clicked4': 0,
};

readyButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    question.innerHTML = "Let's get started with 2*2";
    question.style.right="800px";
    readyButton.style.display="none";
    answerOne.style.display="block";
    answerTwo.style.display="block";
    answerThree.style.display="block";
    answerFour.style.display="block";
    answerOneDataT.innerHTML="<8";
    answerTwoDataT.innerHTML="1*1";
    answerThreeDataT.innerHTML="-2*4";
    answerFourDataT.innerHTML="1+2";
});

for(let i=0; i<1; i++) {

answerOne.addEventListener("click", function() {
    possibilities['clicked1']++;
    question.innerHTML=(nextQuestions[i++]);
    answerOneDataT.innerHTML=(nextAnswers[i++]);
    answerTwoDataT.innerHTML=(nextAnswers[i++]);
    answerThreeDataT.innerHTML=(nextAnswers[i++]);
    answerFourDataT.innerHTML=(nextAnswers[i++]);
    return;
});

answerTwo.addEventListener("click", function() {
    possibilities['clicked2']++;
    question.innerHTML=(nextQuestions[i++]);
    answerOneDataT.innerHTML=(nextAnswers[i++]);
    answerTwoDataT.innerHTML=(nextAnswers[i++]);
    answerThreeDataT.innerHTML=(nextAnswers[i++]);
    answerFourDataT.innerHTML=(nextAnswers[i++]);
    return;
});

answerThree.addEventListener("click", function() {
    possibilities['clicked3']++;
    question.innerHTML=(nextQuestions[i++]);
    answerOneDataT.innerHTML=(nextAnswers[i++]);
    answerTwoDataT.innerHTML=(nextAnswers[i++]);
    answerThreeDataT.innerHTML=(nextAnswers[i++]);
    answerFourDataT.innerHTML=(nextAnswers[i++]);
    return;
});

answerFour.addEventListener("click", function() {
    possibilities['clicked4']++;
    question.innerHTML=(nextQuestions[i++]);
    answerOneDataT.innerHTML=(nextAnswers[i++]);
    answerTwoDataT.innerHTML=(nextAnswers[i++]);
    answerThreeDataT.innerHTML=(nextAnswers[i++]);
    answerFourDataT.innerHTML=(nextAnswers[i++]);
    return;
});

};
```

Comment: What is `answerOne` ?

Comment: I don't think that I understand the question, but I doubt that it's correct to have a loop  just for the index i=0 (you are looping while i<1), and to increment the loop index five times in the event listener.

Comment: It just references a div in HTML.

Comment: @The Nuthouse can you please share fiddle or complete code.

Comment: Can you add some html & error because its not easy to understand

Comment: Now I added the full code you should get a decent idea of the basic html going into it

Comment: @The Nuthouse  we need to run the code so we need **html**

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about your HTML structure, I have put a sample HTML. The things that you need to note or need to make changes for avoiding undefined error are:

- Add enough data on `nextAnswers` & `nextQuestions`, Check array index exist before showing next question & answer options
- Avoid for loop. Do not need to increment `i` all the time if you are handling in click.
- Use another variable as `i` for handling questions. Here I added `q`.

```js
var readyButton = document.getElementById("readyButton"); // since people asked for full code
var question = document.getElementById("question");
var answerOne = document.getElementById("answer1");
var answerTwo = document.getElementById("answer2");
var answerThree = document.getElementById("answer3");
var answerFour = document.getElementById("answer4");
var answerOneData = document.getElementById("answer1data");
var answerTwoData = document.getElementById("answer2data");
var answerThreeData = document.getElementById("answer3data");
var answerFourData = document.getElementById("answer4data");
var answerOneDataT = document.getElementById("answer1dataT");
var answerTwoDataT = document.getElementById("answer2dataT");
var answerThreeDataT = document.getElementById("answer3dataT");
var answerFourDataT = document.getElementById("answer4dataT");
var nextAnswers = ["", "24", "25.5", "15", "32", "", "a statement", "a question", "a sentence", "a metaphor", "", "24", "25.5", "15", "32", "", "a statement", "a question", "a sentence", "a metaphor", "", "24", "25.5", "15", "32", "", "a statement", "a question", "a sentence", "a metaphor"];
var nextQuestions = ["Find x in the equation: 2x+12=63", "This is an example of...", "Q 4", "Q 5", "Q 6", "Q 7"];
let possibilities = {
  'clicked1': 0,
  'clicked2': 0,
  'clicked3': 0,
  'clicked4': 0,
};

readyButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  question.innerHTML = "Let's get started with 2*2";
  question.style.right = "800px";
  readyButton.style.display = "none";
  answerOne.style.display = "block";
  answerTwo.style.display = "block";
  answerThree.style.display = "block";
  answerFour.style.display = "block";
  answerOneDataT.innerHTML = "<8";
  answerTwoDataT.innerHTML = "1*1";
  answerThreeDataT.innerHTML = "-2*4";
  answerFourDataT.innerHTML = "1+2";
});

var i = q = 0;

answerOne.addEventListener("click", function() {
  possibilities['clicked1']++;
  question.innerHTML = (nextQuestions[q++]);
  answerOneDataT.innerHTML = (nextAnswers[i++]);
  answerTwoDataT.innerHTML = (nextAnswers[i++]);
  answerThreeDataT.innerHTML = (nextAnswers[i++]);
  answerFourDataT.innerHTML = (nextAnswers[i++]);
  return;
});

answerTwo.addEventListener("click", function() {
  possibilities['clicked2']++;
  question.innerHTML = (nextQuestions[q++]);
  answerOneDataT.innerHTML = (nextAnswers[i++]);
  answerTwoDataT.innerHTML = (nextAnswers[i++]);
  answerThreeDataT.innerHTML = (nextAnswers[i++]);
  answerFourDataT.innerHTML = (nextAnswers[i++]);
  return;
});

answerThree.addEventListener("click", function() {
  possibilities['clicked3']++;
  question.innerHTML = (nextQuestions[q++]);
  answerOneDataT.innerHTML = (nextAnswers[i++]);
  answerTwoDataT.innerHTML = (nextAnswers[i++]);
  answerThreeDataT.innerHTML = (nextAnswers[i++]);
  answerFourDataT.innerHTML = (nextAnswers[i++]);
  return;
});

answerFour.addEventListener("click", function() {
  possibilities['clicked4']++;
  question.innerHTML = (nextQuestions[q++]);
  answerOneDataT.innerHTML = (nextAnswers[i++]);
  answerTwoDataT.innerHTML = (nextAnswers[i++]);
  answerThreeDataT.innerHTML = (nextAnswers[i++]);
  answerFourDataT.innerHTML = (nextAnswers[i++]);
  return;
});
```

```html
<button id="readyButton">Ready</button>

<div id="question"></div>

<a id="answer1">
  <div id="answer1dataT"></div>
</a>
<a id="answer2">
  <div id="answer2dataT"></div>
</a>
<a id="answer3">
  <div id="answer3dataT"></div>
</a>
<a id="answer4">
  <div id="answer4dataT"></div>
</a>

<div id="answer1data"></div>
<div id="answer2data"></div>
<div id="answer3data"></div>
<div id="answer4data"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your for loop increments the index after each iteration, which is unnecessary since your loop body already increments the index.

Comment: Wow, I never even thought of that, so there's no need for the loop at all?